# Downloading an excel issue from asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an issue with excel downloading with one of my aspx page. Excel file size is 256KB only.

File downloading from all aspx pages except from one aspx page. I am not understanding why this is happening. Not only that, It is working on DEV and QA environments but when we pushed the same code to production. it is not working.

### Updates

Download code on Master Page menu item.

### MasterPage

```
ElseIf e.Item.Text = "Download" Then              
             ResponseHelper.DownloadExcel()
```

### ResponseHelper.vb

Public Shared Sub DownloadExcel()
        GenerateData()
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub GenerateData()
        Dim response As HttpResponse
        response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response

```
    Dim sqlDs As New DataSet
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim SqlCnn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(AppSettings("dbKey"))

    --All ADO.Net statements here

    If sqlDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim dtAllDownload As DataTable = sqlDs.Tables(0)
        Dim dtChinaManufacturing As New DataTable
        Dim dtChinaHealthcare As New DataTable
        Dim dtChinaManagement As New DataTable
        Dim dtChinaSelling As New DataTable

        Dim dv As DataView
        dv = New DataView(sqlDs.Tables(0), "GL_Source='Manufacturing'", "Id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        dtChinaManufacturing = dv.ToTable

        dv = New DataView(sqlDs.Tables(0), "GL_Source='Healthcare'", "Id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        dtChinaHealthcare = dv.ToTable

        dv = New DataView(sqlDs.Tables(0), "GL_Source='Management'", "Id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        dtChinaManagement = dv.ToTable

        dv = New DataView(sqlDs.Tables(0), "GL_Source='Selling'", "Id", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
        dtChinaSelling = dv.ToTable

        dv.Dispose()


        Using pck As New ExcelPackage()
            'Create the worksheets
            Dim wsAll As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("All")
            Dim wsChinaManufacturing As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Manufacturing")
            Dim wsChinaHealthcare As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Healthcare")
            Dim wsChinaManagement As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Management")
            Dim wsChinaSelling As ExcelWorksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Selling")

            'Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1

            wsAll.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtAllDownload, True)
            If dtChinaManufacturing.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                wsManufacturing.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManufacturing, True)
            End If

            If dtChinaHealthcare.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                wsChinaHealthcare.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtHealthcare, True)
            End If

            If dtChinaManagement.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                wsChinaManagement.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtManagement, True)
            End If

            If dtChinaSelling.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                wsChinaSelling.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(dtSelling, True)
            End If

            'wsAll.Cells(1, 1, dtAllDownload.Rows.Count - 1, dtAllDownload.Columns.Count).AutoFitColumns(30)
            wsAll.defaultColWidth = 20

            'Write it back to the client

            Dim filename As String = "FullExtract_" & Now.Year.ToString & Now.Month.ToString & Now.Day.ToString & ".xlsx"
            response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" & filename)
            response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray())
            response.End()

        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

### Aspx Page where this download giving an error.

http://uploading.com/files/18b59f94/Observations.aspx/

### error screenshot

[image]

Comment: So you DO know how to ask questions  :) http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10068672/revisions ... I voted to reopen the question but it was too late.

Comment: If the same code works in other environments then I think you should double check everything else other than your code.

Comment: Hey shoban, I asked moderator to delete that post and keep this post fresh. Let see whats going to happen. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever tried to use another content type?
Try "application/vnd.ms-excel" instead.

Good Luck!